# What information is missing to be able to answer this question asking how one can use a dark background theme for the cells for MS Excel 365 (online)?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

I asked [How can I use a dark background theme for the cells for Microsoft Excel 365 (online)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/166044/18147). The question was closed by a mod who commented:

> Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/166044/edit) the question to include the information necessary to answer it. External links and images are helpful but shouldn't supplant relevant details. [Blindspots](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/197518/blindspots)**♦** [Aug 12 at 22:57](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/166044/how-can-i-use-a-dark-background-theme-for-the-cells-for-microsoft-excel-365-onl#comment160348_166044)

I replied:

> @BlindSpots thanks, the question is "How can I use a dark background theme for the cells for Microsoft Excel 365 (online)?". What information is missing to be able to answer it? [Franck Dernoncourt](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/18147/franck-dernoncourt) [Aug 12 at 23:03](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/166044/how-can-i-use-a-dark-background-theme-for-the-cells-for-microsoft-excel-365-onl#comment160349_166044)

but I didn't receive any response. Therefore, I am asking here on Meta: What information is missing to be able to answer this question asking how one can use a dark background theme for the cells for MS Excel 365 (online)?